# How to get output of inner layer of nested model correctly?

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to build SSD on a base of pre-trained MobileNetV2. So I need to get output from several layers of MobileNet core, add some Convolutions, priors, Reshaping, Concatenate... And finally, then trying to make a model: `model = Model(inputs=img_input, outputs=out)`, I have a problem with  'Graph disconnection'.
Here is my pseudocode:

```
img_input = Input((224,224,3))
conv_model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', 
                    include_top=False,
                    alpha=0.35,
                    pooling=None,                        
                    input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
block14 = conv_model.get_layer('block_14_project_BN').output
block14_box_conf = Conv2D(...)(block14)
block14_box_loc = Conv2D(...)(block14)
block14_priors = PriorBox(...)(block14_box_loc)
# same for other blocks
# Reshaping, Concatinations... softmax for conf...
model = Model(inputs=img_input, outputs=out)
```

And finally, I have an error:

```
 Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "input_1". 
 The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

I may build MobileNet "by bricks", but will unable to load weights in this case. And I need to understand the reason of this error.

Also, this error appears if I'm trying to use the output of some inner layer of the nested model, even in not such complicated cases like SSD.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how lazy the lazy calculations and static graphs are static, an order of layers you are calling matters.
I should use the output of the entire nested model first. For example:

```
model_out = conv_model(img_input)
model_out_box_conf = Conv2D(...)(model_out)
model_out _box_loc = Conv2D(...)(model_out)
model_out_priors = PriorBox(...)(model_out_box_loc)
```

And only after that I can call to inner layers:

```
block14 = conv_model.get_layer('block_14_project_BN').output
block14_box_conf = Conv2D(...)(block14)
block14_box_loc = Conv2D(...)(block14)
block14_priors = PriorBox(...)(block14_box_loc)
```